# MVC.NET add extra parameter to resx (localisation)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, localization, resx

Hi I'm creating a MVC project, with localisation. The project also consists of a small quiz

The questions and answers are in a localisation file (resx), but I need to add points to the answers.

Is there an easy way to add (map) an extra parameter (points) to the translated content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put string formatter tokens into the text in your resource files.  So your text would be:

```
Question10 | "This question is worth {0} points."
```

Then in your code you could do:

```
string.Format(Resources.QuizQuestions.Question10, 15);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, altough this is not what I meant. I need to map the points to the answer. Every answer gives different points

Comment: Ahh, I see.  There's no way to add an extra property in the resource file itself.  There's only the Key and the Value.  What you describe sounds like it would be best stored in a database. You could store the key of the resource item in the database as well and still use the localization framework.

Comment: I Should take a look at the resourceprovider and factory, but well I don't have the time atm :). So I just made a mappting table in the database with the points. It's dirty but hey. Thanks for the answer anyway